# Calling a class member function gives TypeError

Tags: python

I am working with a library which has the following code for a Python class (edited by myself to find a minimal working example):

```
class Foo(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self._bar = 0

  @property
  def Bar(self):
    return self._bar
```

If I then run the following:

```
foo = Foo()
x = foo.Bar()
```

I get an error message:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

So, it seems the error is telling me that it thinks `Bar()` is an `int`, rather than a function. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a **property**! that means that when you get it as an attribute it is the return value, if you want it to be a method then don't make it a property.

to use a property just use `foo.Bar` and it will return the value.

Answer (score 3):

`foo.Bar` is the correct way to use

property converts the class method into a read only attribute.

```
class Foo(object):

      def __init__(self):
        self._bar = 0

      @property
      def Bar(self):
        return self._bar

      @Bar.setter
      def Bar(self, value):
        self._bar = value


foo = Foo()
print(foo.Bar)  # called Bar getter
foo.Bar = 10  # called Bar setter
print(foo.Bar)  # called Bar getter
```